# Something is going wrong with this CSS code

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm making a recent VIP list for a Minecraft server that I work and it seems good on Dreamweaver: [check the pastebin's link]

But when I check it on the website, I got this buggy thing:
[check the pastebin's link]

Why is this happening?
My code:
[check the pastebin's link]

http://pastebin.com/SErKf1Rf

Comment: there are errors in your code. f.e. duplicate use of IDs and more. check your code with [a validator](http://validator.w3.org), please.

Comment: Just a suggestion since it looks like you're new: your question is written in a way that makes the people answering you do too much work. You say you have a "buggy thing", but you don't explain. Instead you force people to go figure it out. You will get more answers and will not get downvoted as much if you take more time to describe exactly what the problem is and what you've done to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is:

```
.players {
  -moz-column-count: 8;
  -webkit-column-count: 8;
  column-count: 8;
}
```

Remove all 3 `column-count` lines, and the white er... thing disappears. I'm not sure why you're using column count along with a table anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The column-count seems to be the problem in .players. Remove them and it seems to work.